# Carrierwave and tmp files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave

When validation fails on an image within my form carrierwave creates a copy of the image in the tmp folder, I have noticed that sometimes a cached copy is used to render the image or in my case the @tempfile path, which seems to retrieve the image from the tmp directory anyway.

```
"animal_images_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"image_cache"=>"", "image"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fbc841d1e90 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20140926-7391-1j7crf4>, @original_filename="cat.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"animal[animal_images_attributes][0][image]\"; filename=\"cat.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">, "_destroy"=>"false"}
```

You will see that image is set to

```
"image"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fbc841d1e90 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20140926-7391-1j7crf4>
```

which in my case is pulling an image from

```
/tmp/1411739943-7391-1974
```

I want to delete this folder but only have the "image" value to go on. How can I delete the tmp file using this value, is there some kind of conversion going on? If I had the image_cache path available then this would be relatively simple

```
def remove_cache
  image = params[:animal][:animal_images_attributes]["0"]

  cache_name = image["image_cache"]
  # get the cache directory
  cache_dir = cache_name.split('/')
  FileUtils.rm_rf(File.join("#{Rails.root}", "/public/uploads/tmp/", cache_dir))
end

in this case cache_name would be '/tmp/1411739943-7391-1974'
```